# My IF condition is acting weird, HELP C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, mean

I have a problem with my condition:

```
if(pos + strlen(string) > 0){
    printf("#");
    string = &string[pos*-1];               
    pos = 0;                
}
```

in procedure:

```
void text_buffer(bool strict, int x, int y, char *string){
    if(active_buff){
        int pos = active_buff -> width * y + x;

        if(pos < 0){
            int cnt = strlen(string) + pos;
            printf("%d %s", cnt, cnt > 0 ? "true" : "false");

            if(pos + strlen(string) > 0){
                printf("#");
                string = &string[pos*-1];               
                pos = 0;                
            }

            else
                return;
        }
        if(pos >= active_buff -> length - 1)
            return;
        char *copy = &(active_buff -> buff[pos]);
        if(strict)
            for(; x < active_buff -> width && *copy && *string; copy++, string++, x++)
                *copy = *string;
        else
            for(; *copy && *string; copy++, string++)
                *copy = *string;
    }
}
```

For example: When I pass text long 15 characters "Hello World! 99" and variable 'pos' is computed as -2000, then that condition I mentioned is going to be value true.

But, if I store (pos + strlen(string)) into a variable 'cnt' instead leave it computing in condition, then its value is 'false'.

I have no idea, I tried put (pos + strlen(string)) into parentheses in that if condition, but still no luck.

Comment: How about you post *all* of the relevant code? What is `actve_buff` and where is it defined?

Comment: i cannot see where active_buff->width is defined... are you certain its not giving you a garbage value?

Comment: active_buff is not the point of the problem, and it is a global sctructure that defines which buffer is already active in use.

BUFFER *active_buff = NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pos` is `-2000` (as you said in the question) then the expression in the condition:

```
if(pos + strlen(string) > 0) {...}
```

is going to be a very large number (exact value depends on `size_t`'s width on your platform) and is going to true.

This is because you are adding an `int` with an unsigned integer (`strlen()` returns `size_t`) which results in the *unsigned integer type* and is always going to be greater than or equal to zero.

You could do:

```
if(pos + (int)strlen(string) > 0)  {...}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, Thank you. I didnt even realize it returns unsigned integers so it retyped me everything into unsigned.

Now it works correctly :) thank you